# Error: Could not find or load main class when running in TextPad

Tags: java

I looked at other answers for this but nothing seems to work, and the 43-votes one was an answer that is currently way above my head. I'm just starting out in Java. I also did not see any answers regarding getting this error in TextPad.
Here is the program I'm trying to write:

```
public class HelloApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

I hit Ctrl-1 to save it, and then Ctrl-2 to run it. The console comes up with the error in the subject (Error: Could not find or load main class HelloApp).

Here is the variable value of Path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\php;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin
```

I'm currently trying to learn java using Java All-in-One for Dummies (because it's like it speaks to me! =p), and have followed all its instructions to the letter, so I'm a bit stumped. Google has not been kind either.

Thanks!

Edit: This is a response to DRastislav's answer, just better formatted.

```
C:\Users\dennis>cd  C:\Users\dennis\Desktop\Java Stuffs

C:\Users\dennis\Desktop\Java Stuffs>javac HelloApp.java

C:\Users\dennis\Desktop\Java Stuffs>java HelloApp
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloApp
```

My book said I could save programs in any directory. Is there some place I need to be saving them?

Edit 2: Ok, I got it to say Hello, World!. I deleted my HelloApp.class file that was already present, then used javac HelloApp.java to recompile it. Typing java HelloApp did not work, so I tried java -cp . HelloApp and it worked. I guess I just have to type that from now on? Note that this is when I type the program into NotePad and run it from there. TextPad still returns the error when I try to run it.

Comment: how do you compile and run it ?

Comment: did you use javac and compile it? (extending @JigarJoshi's comment..)

Comment: Ctrl+1 normally compiles it. You sure you saved it (with Ctrl+s)? And you're sure you mapped javac and java commands to Ctrl+1 an ctrl+2 properly?

Comment: Ctrl+1 is Compile Java, and Ctrl+2 is Run Java Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it as `HelloApp.java` than  use `javac HelloApp.java` and run it  with `java HelloApp` it should work

Comment: This is what I get when I do that in the cmd console: C:\Users\dennis>cd  C:\Users\dennis\Desktop\Java Stuffs
C:\Users\dennis\Desktop\Java Stuffs>javac HelloApp.java

C:\Users\dennis\Desktop\Java Stuffs>java HelloApp
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloApp

Comment: after running javac HelloApp.java in cmd does JVM prepare .class file? .... in your folder should be HelloApp.class file if yes, java HelloApp should work...

Comment: Got it. It was indeed present, but I had tried so many things so I decided to delete it. Typed javac HelloApp.java, then typed java -cp . HelloApp (as per another answer) and it finally gave me Hello, World!. Typing java HelloApp did not work.